# "Database already exists. Choose a different database name. Cannot attach the file..." error after restoring database of c# win app

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I develop a C# win Application that uses a database "OlgooDB.mdf".

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<OlgooContext, Configuration>());
```

Application--> Migration --> Configuration:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<App.Model.OlgooContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        ContextKey = "App.Model.OlgooContext";

        string dataDirPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\Database";
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", dataDirPath);
    }

    protected override void Seed(App.Model.OlgooContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
}
```

When the connection String is defined as:

```
<connectionStrings>
<clear/>
<add name="OlgooContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = OlgooDB; Integrated Security=True; " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> </connectionStrings>
```

I can restore the database without any problem but when i changed the connection String to:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<clear/>
<add name="OlgooContext" connectionString="Data Source =.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\OlgooDB.mdf; Database=OlgooDB; Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> </connectionStrings>
```

This error occurred after restoring:

> system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception(0x80131904): database 'c:\program files\microsoft sql server\mssql10.sqlexpress\mssql\data\OlgooDB.mdf' already exist. choose a different database name.
>   Cannot attach the file 'D:...\bin\Debug\Database\OlgooDB.mdf' as database 'OlgooDB'...

Restore Function:

```
private void backgroundWorkerRestore_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var context = new OlgooContext())
        {
            string command = "ALTER DATABASE OlgooDB SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE " +
                                                    " RESTORE DATABASE OlgooDB FROM DISK='" + txtRestorePath.Text + "'WITH REPLACE " +
                                                    "ALTER DATABASE OlgooDB SET ONLINE";
            context.Database.CommandTimeout = 360;
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(System.Data.Entity.TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, command);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are trying to alter database while loaded inside same dbContext? Did you try doing same without loading dbContext?

Comment: When the database restoring is done, app needs a restart.  The error happen just after app restarting (database restoring is done successfully but restarting the app failed by system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception(0x80131904) error.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused with connecting to `Express instance` and `localdb`.

Your first connection string is fine to connect to Express instance, OlgooDB database: 
`connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = OlgooDB; Integrated Security=True; " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`

In this case the database is already attached, there is no need to attach it one more time, and it's not a `RESTORE` to give you an error, but your second connection string:

```
"Data Source =.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\OlgooDB.mdf; Database=OlgooDB; Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Here you use the syntax to connect to localdb, where .mdf is not attached and you attach it when you connect to localdb

Of course when you try to CREATE DATABASE FOR ATTACH it fails because the database already exists.

So your connection string N2 is wrong: if you use localdb, you attach .mdf just before you use it. But what you use is instead a database permanently attached, and you do not need to attach it

Comment: I run my application in another PC (after creating setup file with second connection string) but i got the same error just after restoring the database, I don't know what's wrong!

Comment: I already wrote, the second connection string is NOT for Express, but for localdb, you should not use it at all

Comment: You have your database permanently attached to Express instance, but you insist and try to re-attach your mdf when it is already attached, within your connection string

Comment: And kindly give us the solution for the above

Comment: @Daniel Nyamasyo if database is already restored as in OP's case just remove AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\OlgooDB.mdf; from connection string

Comment: Thanks sepupic it has worked, be blessed, and also have folders for images at the root of the project, how can i add them when i'm publishing them